# Append date in multiple format using datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, calendar

I'm using JQuery-UI Calendar. My goal is to identify the day of the week for example `Wednesday` and format the date in the input like this `07/20/2017`.

So far I was able to identify the day of the week using `dateFormat:DD` by splitting the date.

Now the issue is the input field appends the date like this `Wednesday/07/20/2017`. While I would like to append it like `07/20/2017`

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'DD/mm/dd/yy',
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,

    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var day = dateText.split("/");
      console.log(day[0]);

      $(".inner").append(day[0]);

      $("#datepicker").append(day[1]);
    }

  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<input type="text" id="datepicker">

<div class="inner">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,


        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var day = dateText.split("/");
            console.log(day[0]);
            var curDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var dayName = $.datepicker.formatDate('DD', curDate);
            $(".inner").append(dayName);

            $("#datepicker").append(day[1]);
        }

    })
});
```

What I did is this:

1. Change the dateFromat to `'mm/dd/yy'` from 'DD/mm/dd/yy'.
2. In order to get the name of the day i added this two lines of code

   ```
   var curDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
   ```

   var dayName = $.datepicker.formatDate('DD', curDate);